# How to set rel=nofollow as default for links in Org export to html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I need to add `rel=nofollow` for every link in my document but be able to change it using something like: `#+ATTR_HTML: :rel index,follow`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the behavior of the `org-html--anchor` function so that no-follow is the default. A simple example:

```
(define-advice org-html--anchor (:around (orig-func id desc attributes info))
  (funcall orig-func id desc (concat " rel=\"no-follow\"" attributes) info))
```

Note that this isn't fully complete; when you specify your own value for the rel attribute, you'll end up with both.